Simplification of a triple integral
I don't understand this simplification, 
$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1}(12x^2 +2z)dxdydz=\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1}4(x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz$. 
The context for the integral is calcuting the flux of the field $\mathbf{u}(x,y,z) = (4x^3+z,2yz,x+y^2)$ through the surface of the unit sphere, in which the first step is using the divergence thereom. 
$\iint_{x^2+y^2+z^2=1}(\mathbf{u}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{n}})dS=\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1}\text{div} \, \mathbf{u}\, dV$.

Since the unit sphere is completely symmetric, it's easy to see by a reordering of variables (for example, through a change of variables like $T(x,y,z) = (y,x,z)$) that if $f(x,y,z)$ only depends on one variable (say, $f(x,y,z) = g(x)$), then
$$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1}f(x,y,z)dV = \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} g(x) dV = \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} g(y)dV = \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} g(z)dV$$
Moreover, if $g$ is an odd function, then the integral is $0$. In your case,
\begin{align*}
\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} (12x^2 + 2z)dV &= \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 12x^2dV + \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 12}2zdV \\
&= \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 12x^2dV \\
&= \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4x^2dV + \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4x^2dV + \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4x^2dV \\
&= \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4x^2dV + \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4y^2dV + \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4z^2dV \\
&= \iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 1} 4(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)dV
\end{align*}
